# viewZone of originalEditor cannot display in inline-diff-editor

Tags: diff, monaco-editor

first, create diffEditor

```
this.diffEditor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(dom, options);
```

second, get originalEditor

```
this.originalEditor = this.diffEditor.originalEditor;
```

third, addViewZone to originalEditor

```
this.originalEditor.changeViewZones((changeAccessor) => {
    const domNode = doucument.createElement('div');
    changeAccessor.addZone({afterLineNumber: 1, domNode})
})
```

in Chrom, it can work when editor use side-by-side
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iCCN.png)

but, when i switch to inline-diff, it can't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9OLv.png)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2131

Comment: issue: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2131